# How can I create a firebase login for the alexa device?

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, alexa-skills-kit

friends!

I want to create an alexa skill using firebase as a backend. For this skill, the user has to authenticate themself to access the firebase server.

I don't want to use a single login system like google or facebook, cause the user has to be authenticated with firebase.

How can I do that? Is it possible with firebase or do I have to use another system?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your Google real-time database is accessible on the internet, you can authenticate yourself to your own database and get the information you need. That data would then be included in your skill's response for account linking purposes. The account linking process and ability to fetch user IDs is fairly well-documented on the Alexa-side, so there would just be Firebase-specific alterations to make.

More on getting started with account linking for smart home skills can be found here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/account-linking-for-sh-and-other.html